# How to resubmit website for Google AdSense after it was disapproved?

Tags: google-adsense

I have submitted website for Google AdSense but it was disapproved. Now I again want to resubmit the site. But there is no form available as mention in most of the answers in resubmit question.

I go through this link, but it redirected to AdSense homepage after sign in http://www.google.com/adsense.

Comment: I have the same issue regularly and has something to do with the cookies, try using a different browser as that normally works for me (from Firefox to Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to clear your  browsers cookies and the local cache. I find the easiest way is to open an Inprivate browser session and then that should resolve the issue. Seems to be a glitch with the way that Google handles cookies during the sign up process in AdSense.